# Tableau Desktop: Live Vs Extract and Publishing to Tableau Server

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I have a question that I can't seem to find a straightforward answer to. I am loading a roughly 20GB CSV file into Tableau Desktop to create some worksheets for future internal views. Where I am stumbling is whether to first use Extract or Live data source. The data itself will not change, only the reports or worksheets generated based on the data. The computations within the worksheets on Tableau Desktop take forever to complete.

On to the publishing to Tableau Server. I am under the assumption that I must upload my locally stored file to the server for future use. Would it be better to find a network drive to have the Tableau Server data source point to?

In short, what is the best method to manipulate a large dataset on Tableau Desktop and present on Tableau Server? Additionally, what Regex methodology does Tableau follow, as it doesn't seem to follow standards I use for Python.

Thanks!

Comment: You have two very distinct questions. You'll want to split them into separate questions here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

When publishing a workbook with a file-based data source, choose the Include external files option in the publishing to server dialog box. This will eliminate the need to have the file in a networked location accessible by the server.

This approach only works if the data doesn't change. It remains static and embedded in the workbook. Under this option, if the data changes and you want your viz to reflect changes, you would need to update the data in Desktop and republish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you have to connect/load your 20GB csv file into Tableau Desktop for proper visualizations, if I understand your requirement correctly.

Please find below steps to do the same:

1. Yes, you have to manually update your data in that csv file whenever you want to show the same on Tableau (Note: Make sure "Name" of entire csv file & columns remain same)
2. After this on opening Tableau, you have to click on "Refresh data source" to get visualization of latest data present in csv file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiefV.jpg)

For this case, I would say connection (LIVE / EXTRACT) won't help as this there is no role of this, However please use EXTRACT technique as per my understanding (means extract will update once we load latest data)